How are int8 and int16 scalar fields stored in Milvus?
In the Milvus schema.proto, it appears that scalar fields can only be of types BoolArray, IntArray, LongArray, FloatArray, DoubleArray, StringArray, BytesArray, ArrayArray, and JSONArray. While Milvus supports Int8 and Int16 types, it seems these are represented as IntArray. How does Milvus manage the storage of int8 and int16 types within an int32 slice?
Is there any form of packing involved, like storing multiple int8 values in a single int32 index, or do int8 and int16 values occupy the entire 4 bytes?
